# Ubuntu apt-get package configuration screen

Tags: ubuntu, sun-java6-jdk

I am trying to install java 1.6 on Ubuntu (11.04) using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

and i am presented with a screen "Package Configuration" with a OK button I can click on.  I would post the image but new users are not allowed to do so.

Can't seem to get past this point.  Any help would be appreciated.

To save others trouble, in order to find the package, you need to add repository and update with the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ natty partner"
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean a configuration dialog like in this [post](http://joepcremers.com/wordpress/install-sun-java-6-on-ubuntu-9-10/).

[image]

You should be able to select the OK button by using the **Tab key**. Then hit **Enter** to accept.

The library that produces this kind of UI is called ncurses.